# Optimizing a while multi-conditional in Python

Tags: python

I have a condition like this:

```
while A != "fi" and A != "fa" and A != "foo" and A != "fe":
    # code
```

Is there any way to optimize (simplify) that `while`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if `A` is not in a set:

```py
while A not in {"fi", "fa", "foo", "fe"}:
  # do something
```

Comment: Using a set O(1) instead of a list O(n) would be more efficient as the number of elements grows.

Comment: @TerrySpotts: Note: That's a result of a CPython optimization that wasn't added until a 3.0, so if you're still writing for (obsolete) Python 2.7, or any of the elements are not constant literals, it's faster to just use a `tuple` (because Python 2.7 will rebuild the `set` from scratch each time, while 3.x will cache a `frozenset` to avoid rebuilding, if all elements are compile-time constant literals).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
while A not in ["fi","fa","foo","fe"]:
   #code
```